# Replacing a movieclip with another movieclip, keeping the same instance name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm new to actionscript so this question might be a stupid one.

I'm trying to replace a movieclip with another movieclip, while keeping the instance name of the previous.

I have a menu with a selection of buttons, each leading to the same screen with a movieclip and a scrubber bar. I tried defining the movieclip through a variable, then tried redefining it through an event listener function, but I'm guessing I can't do like this:

```
var MC: movieclipsymbol1 = new movieclipsymbol1;


private function selectionscreen(): void {

  selectionscreenbutton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, screenbutton1);
  selectionscreenbutton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, screenbutton2);

  private function screenbutton1(event: MouseEvent): void {
    var MC: movieclipsymbol1 = new movieclipsymbol1;
    movieclipscreen();
  }

  private function screenbutton2(event: MouseEvent): void {
    var MC: movieclipsymbol2 = new movieclipsymbol2;
    movieclipscreen();
  }
}

public function movieclipscreen(): void {
  stage.addChild(MC);
}
```

Because of the scrubber bar code I did, I need to keep the instance for the movieclips the same. Is the approach I'm using completely off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `var MC` from both handlers, as you want your new MC to be accessible from outside of the handlers. But also you need to change the type of class variable `MC` so that it could hold either `movieclipsymbol1` or `movieclipsymbol2`. The most common choice for the type in there is `MovieClip`. So, you have to change your functions like this:

```
var MC:MovieClip = new movieclipsymbol1();
private function screenbutton1(event: MouseEvent): void {
    clearOldMC();
    MC = new movieclipsymbol1();
    movieclipscreen();
}
private function screenbutton2(event: MouseEvent): void {
    clearOldMC();
    MC = new movieclipsymbol2();
    movieclipscreen();
}
private function clearOldMC():void {
    if (MC.parent) MC.parent.removeChild(MC);
}
```

The new function removes the previously displayed movie clip, regardless of its type.

Answer (score -1):

Use "name" property of display object to give the instance name to movieclip.

Comment: Thankyou for replying, can you give me an example please- do you mean using the name property like replacementmovieclip.name = "MC"; Would that work? Would I have to rename the original movieclip defined in the variable?

Comment: @Kaif you should better read the code in question before posting bluntly. See, the code says about instance `MC` instead of something that regards `.name` property.